# ¿Se permite formular una pregunta y auto responderse?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, pregunta-autorespondida

Buenas noches, madrugadas y la hora a la que sea cuando lee este mensaje. Por ningún lado he visto algo de esta manera:

#### "Publicar una pregunta y a los pocos segundos auto-responderse con todos los detalles necesarios".

Quisiera saber si es permitido hacer esto en el tema de puntaje. En lo personal no lo veo como una manera ética para adquirir puntos.

Bendiciones para todos, que tengan un bonito día.

Comment: Si alguien votó por la respuesta o la pregunta, es porque la publicación le fue de utilidad.  ¿Por qué consideras que no sería ético?

Comment: Yes, please, **just do it!**

Comment: Equiso, en mi humilde opinión, no lo considero ético por el mismo hecho que el sitio en español esta recién empezando y hay una gran cantidad de "conocimiento" no traducido, o simplemente no publicado en español. Auto-responderse siento que no debería haber puntos pero eso de las votaciones a favor por otros usuarios, me parece correcto. ¿Me dejo entender?

Comment: Véase http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182/si-vas-a-responder-tu-pregunta-hazlo-antes-de-publicar-la-pregunta

Comment: Yo lo intenté, me respondí mi propia pregunta, y no conozco mucho el inglés, mi respuesta fue original, no fue copiada. Sirve para reflexión propia y para no estropear el contenido inicial de la pregunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Claro que si! debajo del area para hacer la pregunta hay un checkbox que dice:

#### Responde a tu propia pregunta

Esa es la forma usual. Ahí mismo escribirás tu respuesta (al mismo tiempo que haces la pregunta). Por cierto es igual de valido responder poco (o mucho) tiempo después.

Con respecto a los puntos, considera que estarías compartiendo información... eso te hace merecedor de la reputación.